# Argparse - Custom Action With No Argument?

Tags: python, argparse

```
class StartAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print "Hello"

start.add_argument('-s', '--start', action=StartAction)
```

I know normally having the action be something like 'store_true' would prevent the requirement of an argument, but is there a way to use a custom action and still not require an argument to be passed?

So what I want is:

> python example.py -s
>
> Hello

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try adding `nargs=0` to your `start.add_argument`:

```
start.add_argument('-s', '--start', action=StartAction, nargs=0)
```

Comment: ValueError: nargs for store actions must be > 0; if you have nothing to store, actions such as store true or store const may be more appropriate

Comment: I don't agree with @Lucina comment. You may want to call a custom action to have a seamless mapping between parsing arguments and complex actions. I prefere to have Action objects that behave as the parameters of the CLI so I have polymorphism between the CLI itnerface and the object that handles it.

Comment: @Daniel it's not a question of "agreement".  This is an error one can receive when setting `nargs=0`

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I  agree the error exists. I don't agree with the  actions she suggested.

Comment: @Daniel she didn't suggest actions.  That is literally the error message.

Comment: ok @ReinstateMonica, I really don't care ATM. My answer reflected what I thought about it 4 years ago. I don't see the point on necro-bumping  this. Best, D.

Answer (score 8):

As [mgilson suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002123/923794) `nargs=0` does the trick. Since it's intrinsic to your action, I'd put it inside the action:

```
class StartAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, nargs=0, **kw):
        super().__init__(nargs=nargs, **kw)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print "Hello"

start.add_argument('-s', '--start', action=StartAction)
```

And you have your desired behaviour without the redundancy of having to add `nargs=0` to every `add_argument()` call. Neat if you have multiple arguments working in the same way.

However users could still override the default of `nargs=0` which is silly for your use case as demonstrated in the question. So I'd enforce it:

```
class StartAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, nargs=0, **kw):
        if nargs != 0:
            raise ValueError('nargs for StartAction must be 0; it is '
                             'just a flag.')
        super().__init__(nargs=nargs, **kw)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print "Hello"
```

Comment: The former (without the enforcing check) is also exactly what `action="store_const"` does: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e1e8dbb0b99ec78f4567382428fdd46e2244d40/Lib/argparse.py#L890

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who finds this in 2020:
If you attempt to pass nargs=0 in the latest argparse package for python3, it will error with:

```
ValueError: nargs for store actions must be != 0; if you have nothing to store, actions such as store true or store const may be more appropriate
```

The solution you're probably looking for is to pass action="store_const" and const=True

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser
parser.add_argument('-s', '--start', help='Start script or whatever', action="store_const", const=True)
```

This will set the value for parser.start equal to "True" when the -s parameter is passed to main/the rest of the script.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this example after consulting the above and trying out different methods. Here is a class which implements the "Uncount" acount, which is the opposite of the 'count' action.

```
import argparse
class Uncount(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=0, choices=None, const=None, **kwargs):
        if nargs != 0:
            raise ValueError("no arguments to this parameter are allowed")
        if const is not None:
            raise ValueError("this parameter does not permit constants")
        if choices is not None:
            raise ValueError("no choices to this parameter are allowed")
        super(Uncount, self).__init__(option_strings=option_strings, nargs=nargs, dest=dest,**kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        value = getattr(namespace, self.dest, 0)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, value-1)

opts={}
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Report on other teams')
argparser.add_argument(
    '-v','--verbose',dest='verbose',default=0,action='count',
    help='increase log level',
)
argparser.add_argument(
    '-q','--quiet',dest='verbose',default=0,action=Uncount,
    help='increase log level',
)
```

Examples:

```
>>> argparser.parse_args('-q -q'.split())
Namespace(verbose=-2)
>>> argparser.parse_args('-q -v'.split())
Namespace(verbose=0)
>>> argparser.parse_args('-q -v -v'.split())
Namespace(verbose=1)
```